# Frequency of unique character

Tags: r

Im trying to find the number of times a unique gene is found in samples with its respective pvalue

```
df1 <-  read.table(text="
        Gene        id           Seg.mean    pValue    CNA
         Nfib       8410          0.3108     1.381913 gain
         Mycl       8410          2.7320     1.182842 gain
         Mycl       8410          2.7320     1.846275 gain
         Nfib       8411          0.5920     1.381913 gain
         Nfib       8411          1.3090     1.381913 gain
         Mycl       8412          1.6150     5.765442 gain
         Mycl       8411          1.6150     1.846275 gain
",header=TRUE)
```

expected output

```
Gene    ID           Freq. of id   pValue
Nfib    8410,8411        2           1.381913
Mycl    8410,8411,8412   3           1.182842,1.846275,5.765442
```

Comment: @tospig, yes. It would give us a better understanding of the data

Comment: Where there are multiple p-values and IDs, do you want them in the same row of the data frame, AND in the same column, or across multiple columns?

Comment: @tospig..different column would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### sol'n:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  summarise(ID = paste0(unique(id), collapse=", "),
            pval = paste0(unique(pValue),collapse=", "), 
            n = n_distinct(id))
```

#### result:

```
  Gene               ID                         pval n
1 Mycl 8410, 8412, 8411 1.182842, 1.846275, 5.765442 3
2 Nfib       8410, 8411                     1.381913 2
```

#### breakdown:

1. we want to evaluate on `Gene` (unit of analysis) and so `group_by(Gene)`.
2. then create new variables which correspond to `paste0(var,collapse=", ")`. This is applied *per `Gene`*.
3. count the number of distinct ids. Again applied *per `Gene`*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use data.table to get very close to the result you want to achieve:

```
library(data.table)

df1<-data.table(df1)
df1[,
list(ID = paste(unique(id), collapse=','),
     "Freq. of id"=length(unique(id)), 
     pValue=paste(unique(pValue), collapse=",")),
keyby=list(Gene)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
> ddply(data.frame(df1), .(Gene), summarise,ID=paste(unique(id), collapse=","),pValue=paste(unique(pValue), collapse=","),Freq = length(unique(id)))
  Gene             ID                     pValue Freq
1 Mycl 8410,8412,8411 1.182842,1.846275,5.765442    3
2 Nfib      8410,8411                   1.381913    2
```